# How to resize images in pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib

Whenever I generate an image it very easy to zoom it manually using pylab, i.e. drawing a rectangle around the region we intend to zoom in. I was wondering if it was possible coding this operation.

Here is an example code, where I generate a 100x100 image with random values on each row:

```
from random import *
from pylab import *
from numpy import *


a=ones((100,100))
image=array([dummy*random() for dummy in a])

imshow(image,extent=[0,1]+[5,6])
```

In the above example our image extends from 0 to 1 in the x-axis and from 5 to 6 in the y-axis. How can show a zoom on the image, let's say in the region 0.5

Comment: When you don't want to copy a lot of irrelevant code, which makes sense and is fine, you should create a short dummy image generator.  The idea is that someone should be able to copy what you've posted and play around with it, so they can immediately try their hands at solving the problem, rather than waste time writing their own placeholders.  (This is the "self-contained" part of SSCCE: see [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html#module-scipy.ndimage.interpolation) to resize array.

Edit:

Sorry, I misunstand your question. You can use `xlim()` and `ylim()` to set the range of X and Y axis:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

y, x = np.ogrid[-1:1:100j, -1:1:100j]
z = np.sin(4*(x**2+y**2))

pl.imshow(z, origin="lower", extent=(-1,1,-1,1))
pl.xlim(-0.5, 0)
pl.ylim(0.5, 1.0)
pl.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, that was easier than I thought.